# C/C++ compare only once

Tags: c++, c, loops

I have a while loop inside which I want to do a specific operation only once, and a different operation for all other loop runs.

```
while (..) {
  if ( 0 == count ) {
       // do_this
  } else {
       // do_that
  }
  count++;
}
```

Here, `count` needs to be compared with `0` only once but it is unnecessarily compared in each loop run. Is there an alternative way where the comparison happens only once and once succeeded is not again called?

Comment: Are you sure that the performance hit is relevant? Rewriting the code without the `if()` block _might_ be faster, but is it as clear for developers as it is now?

Comment: You shouldn't be concerned with this too much because this is exactly the kind of `if` CPU's branch prediction algorithm handles perfectly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Either do the thing for `count == 0` before the loop, or if that's not possible (because it's in the middle of other things that are being done) just write your code to be human readable and any half decent compiler will figure it out for you. Or it will not figure it out and the branch predictor in the CPU will do the job. Either way a nano-optimization like this will most likely cost you more time reading the code than you'll ever save on execution time.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the branch predictor. That will certainly kick in if the loop has sufficient iterations. And if it doesn't, no need to bother anyway.

Answer (score 8):

```
{
    // do_this
}
count = 1; /*assuming count previously started at zero*/
while (..) {
    // do_that
    count++; /*although some folk prefer ++count as it's never slower than count++*/
}
```

is better

Comment: You must warp anything with if(...) statememt, otherwise it's not the same.

Comment: Arpegius: indeed you do; `// do this` should be in braces. I've amended the answer.

Comment: thanks, that's cool. But it won't look clean when I have a while loop with `getline` e.g. when I'm reading a file and want to do some operation only for first line of file. In that case, with your scheme I'll need to call `getline` twice once in `do_this` and at another time in `while(..)`

Comment: I would love to give you +1 because this seems to be a nice answer, but it is not satisfying me at all. Shouldn't be `//do_this` part of a if statement, or do I just get your whole idea wrong?

Comment: @user13107: it may well not be clean but it will be *clear*.

Comment: @Zaibis - I am assuming that count was zero at the beginning; see program comment. If not then it's trivial to tweak.

Comment: Ah ok, thats not that nice as i thought before, i missed your idea for real. but anyway +1 for correct answer!

Comment: Btw, which way is better practice, the one in the question or the one suggested in this answer?

Comment: @user13107 It's better practice to write readable code that's easy to understand and leaving optimizations to the compiler. Write what is the most easy for you to read and understand.

Comment: I've encountered this problem a dozen times or so and always opt for a solution that doesn't involve unnecessary checking of a counting variable. Indeed a good compiler may optimise it out but when building multiplatform stuff, there's bound to be one that doesn't. Also doesn't sit well when debugging. So I'd always do it my way ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**Don't optimize unnecessarily!**

The cost of the compare is 1-2 clock cycles and as mentioned by Art it could be optimized away by the compiler. The cost is absolutely negligable when compared to the cost of reading from a file. The performance of your program will be bound by I/O anyway (either memory reads or disk reads depending on whether the file is mapped in memory).

In this case you should write the code so that it is easy to maintain.

Comment: While the cost of compare is small, the cost of a branch is generally pretty big. Not on the order of I/O, of course, but in a performance-critical piece of code, you do *not* want to stall the pipeline.

Comment: @Angew The cost of the branch in this particular example is as close to optimal case for any branch predictor as you can get. You will either not stall the pipeline or you repeat the loop so few times that this whole optimization is meaningless.

Comment: @Art Yes, you said so in your answer, and I gave you +1 for it. But this answer does not mention that at all: it seems to say "even if it's not optimised away, the compare is just 1-2 clock cycles." Without saying why it's super-optimal for branch prediction, it sounds dangerous to me.

Comment: @Angew Very true, sorry about that. Actually, I'd go a level further and say that theorizing about branch predictors and mentioning "clock cycles" at the level of this question is redundant and possibly even giving bad ideas to the asker. The answer should just be "write readable code and hit your knee with a hammer any time you try to be clever or optimize".